# Is it possible (aka safe) to resize a partition while the system is running?

Tags: partitioning, ext4

I'm talking about resizing my root partition (/), while the system is on (I know that's usually impossible, but I'm just hoping there is some way to do it). I want to know if there is some way I can boot the system up in read-only mode (without a live cd, just in case), and resize /.

If it can't work, I understand, as that is what I already know to be the case (but you never know =P)

Comment: Open another question about how to do it : http://askubuntu.com/questions/23067/how-do-you-resize-a-partion-live

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some filesystems support "on-line" resizing, and in that case I would consider it reasonably safe unless the manpage/program warns it is not.

Most filesystems that support "on-line resize" only support making it larger (e.g. [XFS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/xfs_growfs.8.html), [ext2/3/4](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/resize2fs.8.html), [reiserfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/resize_reiserfs.8.html)).

Btrfs supports [on-line growing *and* shrinking](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Resizing_partitions_.28shrink.2Fgrow.29), but of course it's not as stable as a long-existing filesystem like XFS or ext4 yet.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the earlier comment. I would just add to make GOOD BACKUPS before attempting anything like this. I also found that I can do this only if the partition is unmounted, as well as all partitions after this one on the hard disk. I saw this when attempting to merge two partitions together, by first deleting one, freeing up space, and then adding the freed space to an existing partition.

I was told that all partitions above the one to be increased must be unmounted first. I did unmount it, and merged the partition. It was successful.

BUT do backups backups backups backups ....................did I say BACKUP ?

Comment: What about online partition backup? :) He can't unmount / filesystem