# ubuntu 18.04 boot error ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2

I bought a new laptop with rtx 2060 a few days ago. I installed ubuntu 18.04 dual boot. After some time, I tried to increase the ubuntu storage but when I plugged in the live usb with ubuntu inside and then  choose "try ubuntu without installing" my screen turned black, but i could hear the ubuntu running in the background. After that i shut down the laptop and reboot it, but when i choose to boot ubuntu I faced this error " error ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)" and I was not able to log into ubuntu. I updated the BIOS, but nothing happened , what can i do?

Comment: 1) How were you going to increase the storage? A) Add another drive device, B) assign previously unassigned space to Ubuntu use, or C) shrink another partition  and give its space to Ubuntu?  2) Are you able to boot from your newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 without the LiveUSB? 3) What make and model laptop? 4) Please run `sudo parted -l` once you have booted, copy the result, and paste that into your question with [edit] along with answers to 1) - 3). Please do not use Add Comment; instead use [edit] as it will allow formatting of your answers, whereas Add Comment loses all formatting.

Comment: thank you for your effort, i just update the graphics drivers and the problem solved. i tried to execute the steps of this link "https://askubuntu.com/questions/871825/add-more-disk-space-for-linux-from-windows-in-a-dual-bootable-machine " but when i inserted the usb drive  and clicked "try ubuntu without installing" something changed the graphics drivers and after that this error occured.

Comment: Then, may I suggest you write an answer below, then mark it by clicking the check mark to show that answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

I installed the latest Nvidia drivers (nvidia-440) for my GPU from tty and the problem solved.