# allot more space to ubuntu on laptop dual booted with windows 10 pro

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning

My lenovo p50 laptop has 64gb dd4ram and 1TB SSD.
I don't remember how but I allocated 500gb to ubuntu and 500gb to win10.
However, my ubuntu is complaining that it is running out of space. It shows only 75GB is available when in reality I have 500gb.

I looked at : [Give more Hard disk space to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727112/give-more-hard-disk-space-to-ubuntu?rq=1)  and [Add more disk space for linux from windows in a dual bootable machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871825/add-more-disk-space-for-linux-from-windows-in-a-dual-bootable-machine/871858) ; but didn't quite follow the solutions.

Please tell me to allot all the 500gb for usage safely without breaking anything.

vivek@vivek:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

```
[sudo] password for vivek: 
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           953.9G            
├─sda4 ntfs   453.2G            Windows
├─sda2 ntfs     450M            Recovery
├─sda5 ext4   436.3G /          
├─sda3 vfat     100M /boot/efi  
├─sda1          128M            
└─sda6 swap    63.7G [SWAP]   

vivek@vivek:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: blah blah blah blah blah

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          34     262177    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2      264192    1185791    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda3     1185792    1390591    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda4     1390592  951830527 950439936 453.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   951830528 1866817535 914987008 436.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  1866817536 2000408575 133591040  63.7G Linux swap
```

Update: 
looks like somehow something is taking up all my space :(

```
vivek@vivek:~$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     6.3G  9.4M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda5      ext4      430G  381G   27G  94% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      32G   56M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs      32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3      vfat       96M   29M   68M  30% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     6.3G   88K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Windows 10Pro partition has no personal data whatsoever, is there a safe way to allot ubuntu another 250 gb without harming ubuntu or win10 in any way. I have really important stuff on my ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

1. **Backup your data**, and test your backup.
2. Find what is using space, for the GUI:`baobab`, for the command line: `ncdu` and decide if you can save some space by deleting files, or going further.
3. Boot Ubuntu from a DVD or USB, and use `gparted` to resize your partitions. (There is absolutely no risk of losing any data, since you've folowed step 1).

Comment: how do I view the contents and empty : `/dev/sda5      ext4      430G  381G   27G  94% / `  my laptop is less than 1 month old and it is so full which it makes no sense.