# Is it possible to resize a partition in use?

Tags: server, hard-drive

I have a partition in use, `ext4` and the operating system is already run, is it possible resize that partition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you resize a live partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23067/how-do-you-resize-a-live-partition) and [Is it possible (aka safe) to resize a partition while the system is running?](https://askubuntu.com/q/13250/)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to resize a mounted `ext4` partition.

This is possible only for `btrfs` but only "the right-hand border".

You can boot with Ubuntu LiveUSB and resize it this way.

Comment: `man resize2fs` contradicts this. The mounted file system can be expanded with any modern kernel.

Comment: That's true. But it can't be shrinked. So generally "resize" only one way. `btrfs` can both ways.

Comment: I have never seen a case where one of my customers has requested that their disk allocation been reduced. In my experience, `resize` is only one way - increase the disk size.

Comment: I shrinked filesystems very many times. E.g. if I wanted to create another partition.